# How can I go from List View to Detalied view for each List item?

Tags: java, android, listview, button, master-detail

I'm developing an Android app, and I have a ListView.
Each item is a card that contains some text, an image and a Button.

What I want to do is that when you click on a specific Button, for example the Button from Global Warming item, I want to show up an Activity with more details (another Activity or something).
But for each Button I want to display different data on same Activity.

Another question: When I click the Button, can I open a single Activity showing different data?
Because I did the "opening Activity part", but I don't know how to send something to the Activity to tell it which Button has just been clicked.

P.S.: for showing each item in the ListView, I'm using a CustomAdapter.

Here is my ListView

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjcIv.jpg]

Comment: Google for `android master detail listview`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you can use listview.setOnItemClickListener and in clicking an item you can get associated data from list or arraylist  whatever you are using and start activity with details and pass those details as extras to this activity and get it into the new detailed activity  and populate UI.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is

1. When a button clicked store in a variable that which button is clicked
2. send that button to next activity by intent ( putextra ).
3. In the second activity first get the information which button is clicked then show data accordingly

From coding point

let us have three buttons b1,b2,b3  the we do following in `onCreate()` method

```
b1.setOnclickListener(this);
b2.setOnclickListener(this);
b3.setOnclickListener(this);
```

Then in 'onClick()'

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

    int selected; 
    switch(v.getId())
    {
       case R.id.id_of_b1: 
         selected=1;
         break;
       case R.id.id_of_b2: 
         selected=2;
         break;
       case R.id.id_of_b3: 
         selected=3;
         break;
     }

  Intent intent = new Intent(Thisactivity.this, Secondactivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("int_value",selected);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then in second activity get the value of the integer variable with

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int temp = intent.getIntExtra("int_value", 0); //0 is default value (no button was clicked from listview,, other button was clicked if there any)
```

Now show your content with a if

```
switch(temp){
    case 1:
        //Do Something
        break;
    case 2:
        // Do Something
        break;
    case 3:
        // Do Something
        break;
}
```